# Find files greater than x kB/MB/GB in size, and also show their size

Tags: bash, shell-script, files, find

I'd like a simple command (perhaps using `find`) which finds all files > some size in bytes, kilobytes, megabytes, or gigabytes, and which prints their size as they are found.

This command, for instance, finds all files > 10 MB, but does not show their size, unfortunately:

```bsh
find . -size +10M
```

### See also:

1. [Files greater than 1 GB and older than 6 months](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/203129/files-greater-than-1-gb-and-older-than-6-months/203131#203131) - doesn't show size
2. [Linux show files in directory larger than 1 GB and show size](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/622979/linux-show-files-in-directory-larger-than-1-gb-and-show-size) - accepted answer looks more-complicated than expected, and I don't need sorting.
3. [Find files greater than X value, sort by size, show in ls format](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/486361/find-files-greater-than-x-value-sort-by-size-show-in-ls-format) - I don't need nor want `ls` format, and main answer may not work with spaces
4. https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-use-find-command-to-search-for-files-based-on-file-size

Comment: Does this help? [Get the exact size of files retrieved by find output](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/543676/get-the-exact-size-of-files-retrieved-by-find-output)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I get the find command to print out the file size with the file name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64649/#64691)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about just:

```
find -size +10M -exec du -h {} \;
```

Comment: Can you explain how `exec` works please, and why we need `{}` and `\ ` and `;` ?

Comment: As far as I know, "find" alone does not have an option to show file size. "exec" runs a shell command, { } is a placeholder for where the file name goes in the command, \\; is for ending the line. The difference between this and the more complex answers you originally linked is that this is shorter and easier to understand (presumably), but might fail if you have special characters in your filenames (e.g. if you have a file named doc*.txt).

Comment: The above should have \; not \\;

Comment: works also on toybox

Comment: Note that `-size` compares size, while `du` reports disk usage (and for files of type *directory*, that's disk usage of the directory itself + all files and directories than can be found in its traversal, recursively. Note that standard `find` requires at least one file to be passed as argument.

Answer (score 4):

Note that the `M` in `find . -size +10M`, is a GNU extension.
The GNU implementation of `find` has another extension: `-printf` that you can use to print the size of those files:

```
find . -size +10M -printf '%s %p\n'
```

To report the `s`ize and `p`ath of the files that are more than 10MiB (mebibytes, not megabytes¹) large.

Here, you could also use `zsh` and its `stat` builtin and glob qualifiers:

```
zmodload zsh/stat
stat -nL +size -- **/*(LM+10)
```

That prints the size after the file path. Also note that contrary to `find`, that excludes hidden files by default (you can add them back with the `D` qualifier).

Or to `print` `r`aw on `2` `C`olumns (`a`cross):

```
stat -nLA report +size -- **/*(LM+10)
print -raC2 -- $report
```

Note that all those `-size`, `%s`, `+size` consider the file's *size*, which is not the same as the file's *disk usage*² as reported by `du` (or `%b`/`%k` in `gfind -printf`, or `+block` in `zsh`'s stat, though `du` also includes the size of unique files within for files of type *directory*). `find` has no predicate to filter files based on their disk usage.

---

<sup>¹ for files larger than 10 MB (megabyte), you'd need `-size +10000000c` (standard) in `find` or `(L+10000000)` in `zsh`</sup>

<sup>² bigger files generally take up more disk space, but not necessarily and in any case the relation between the the two is not linear.</sup>

Comment: Upvoted. It looks like there's also an option for `%k` for "`The amount of disk space used for this file in 1 KB blocks.`" (per `man find`), but I don't see an option for MB or GB output, oddly enough. I slightly favor the [`find -size +10M -exec du -h {} \;`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/666687/114401) answer, therefore, because it prints in "human-readable" format with an auto-chosen unit (`K`, `M`, or `G`), based on the file's size. I find that a little more usable for most cases, except when I want more precision at the byte-level for scripts and auto-parsing.

Comment: @GabrielStaples I do mention `%b`/`%k` and `du` already in passing in the last  paragraph, but that's about disk usage (cumulative for files of type directory), not size (though the  GNU implementation of `du` has some option to report size instead of disk usage).

Comment: Understood. By the way, since we're talking about disk usage vs size, I did some studies and found some interesting results, which I posted on my website here: [exFAT filesystem _speed_ and _disk usage_ based on cluster size](https://gabrielstaples.com/exfat-clusters/).

Answer (score 0):

If you use zsh and a `ls` that supports `-h` for *human readable sizes*, you can do something like:

```
ls -lhd -- **/*(.Lm+10)
```

which finds all non-hidden files greater than 10MiB in size and does `ls -ldh` on them.  You might get **argument list too long**.  If you do, you could use `zargs` but then you get into as much complication as using `find`.

Also, not to falsely accuse `zsh` of problems but I've seen weirdnesses when doing `**/*` on large directories.  i.e. `ls -ld /**/*(.)`, even with using `zargs` can never end.  But... for smaller jobs, having `zsh` do the work is often more convenient once you get the syntax for `zsh` down into your finger tips.

Comment: Note that I already mention zsh's **/*(LM+10) in  my answer, using zsh's `stat` builtin which avoids the arg list too long issue.

Comment: I wouldn't call `*` excluding "hidden" files.  They are not hidden at all.  They are just not interesting and so the convention is to not list them.  Windows and the Mac GUI actually hides things and the user must do gymnastics to see them.  Mac GUI / Windows is trying and failing to "simplify" or "protect" the user when in fact it only gets in the way.  All in all, I much prefer my original answer to your edited one.